# Character determines the representation?

Tags: lie-groups, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

Consider a semisimple Lie group or a $p$ adic reductive group $G$.

To what extent can the character of a representation as a distribution on $C_c^\infty(G)$ determine the representation?

Comment: As BR indicates (and the context of your question requires) the group representations here are not completely arbitrary. I think the qualifier "irreducible admissible" is safest in both settings.  Such questions are usually more delicate for instance when working over a function field in prime characteristic.   

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a reductive Lie group, the character characterizes an irreducible admissible representation up to infinitesimal equivalence. Referring to Knapp's "Representation Theory, etc", Proposition 10.5 says that two infinitesimally-equivalent irreducible admissible representations have the same character, and Theorem 10.6 says that infinitesimally-inequivalent irreducible admissible representations have linearly independent characters.

For reductive $p$-adic groups, the character characterizes irreducible admissible representations., in that inequivalent irreducible admissible representations have linearly independent characters. See, e.g., Section 17 of [Murnaghan's notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/murnaghan/courses/mat1197/).

Comment: By reductive p-adic group you presumably mean an algebraic group,
such as GL(n,F), Sp(2n,F), or SO(n,F), where the result holds. Maybe this is only a comment for the experts, but as far as I know, there is no proof in the literature if G is a non-linear cover of such a group, and it might not be routine to prove this.

Comment: Jeffrey, thanks for adding your comment. I would not have guessed that. To be clear, are you saying that it may not be known if the characters of inequivalent (admissible, etc) representations of non-linear reductive groups are different?

Comment: Yes, in the p-adic case, that is what I am saying. It is known over R.

Comment: Professor Adams : Chapter 2 of Casselman's notes at leas states this result (Proposition 2.3.1), for an arbitrary locally compact Hausdorff group such that the compact open subgroups form a basis of neighborhoods at the identity (proof is referred to J-L, I haven't checked it).

And independently, a clarification for someone who might be relatively new to the subject and reading this : the original question does not explicitly mention the admissibility assumption. However, it is only for admissible representations that the character is defined on $C_c^{\infty}(G)$ as a distribution.

Comment: anādimadhyānta, the proof in Jacquet/Langlands _looks_ general, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is some subtle assumption there. Perhaps someone will enlighten us :) Additionally, to add to the second part of you comment, in the archimedean case something stronger than admissibility is required for the existence of characters. Wallach (Real Reductive Groups I) requires finite-generation, while Knapp requires a bound on the rate of growth of the multiplicities of the $K$-types. 

Comment: The theorem is proved in the book by Harish-Chandra and van Dijk, but only for linear groups. I'm not an expert in the p-adic case, but my vague recollection is there is a nontrivial technical issue towards the end that requires linearity. The proof in Jacquet Langlands is only for GL(2), at least as stated. Maybe an expert can enlighten us.

Comment: @BR - thanks for the clarification. I had carelessly omitted to state that I was in the p-adic context; and I didn't know there were these separate conditions in the archimedean context.

So you are Prof. Adams are saying that Casselman could possibly have omitted to check that the proof carries over to the case he states it for, contra his claim?

Comment: anādimadhyānta, just so you know, I didn't mean to imply that it wasn't clear you were working $p$-adically. I had been thinking about mentioning the requirement in the archimedean case, and your comment seemed like a good opportunity. It is definitely possible that Casselman implicitly assumed linearity when looking at Jacquet/Langlands (or something!).

Comment: In the $p$-adic setting, as Anadimadhyanta wrote, the answer is yes for admissible complex representations of locally profinite topological groups. Another reference is 

 Bernstein and Zelevinsky : Representations of the group ${\rm GL}(n,F)$, where $F$ is a local non-Archimedean field.
Uspekhi Mat. Nauk 10, No.3, 5-70 (1976), corollary (2.20) page 21.

Comment: Paul, thanks for adding that. Their proof looks pretty solid.

Comment: anādimadhyānta, you are welcome, and thank you for your contributions to this discussion.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; what is more difficult is that the character is given by a locally summable function (not that the character determines the representation). Thanks for the reference and clarification.  